# How does GitHub handle users for mirrored repositories?

Tags: git, github

There are a lot of mirror repositories on GitHub. When users contribute to the original repository, how does GitHub show their profile if they do not have a GitHub account or participate using different credentials?

For example, list of contributors in "https://github.com/apache/cassandra/graphs/contributors" shows members of the original repository but links to their GitHub profile. How does GitHub connect their Apache username to their GitHub profile url?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about guessing the internals of a closed-source repository hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

The profile associated with each commit is based on committer name and email.

If that committer name and email is the same as a GitHub account, I suspect that GitHub account link is used for contribution profiles.